# How to use parseInt at Html side in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used below code for total :

```
<span>  
 {{ ((item.USWIPQtyValue * 1)) + (item.UKWIPQtyValue * 1)}}    </span>
```

Here I can't convert string to int.
So in begining time **NaN** is displayed in **span** tag.
So how to apply parseInt function at html side.

Comment: What value causes the problem?

Comment: When I have no value then it is taking Nan in span then what to do?

Comment: What is `I` in ` I have no value`?

Comment: Have you tried the initialization like I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Try to initiliaze your `item` object correctly before initial load. In javascript, `undefined * 1` is equal to `NaN` (Not a Number) and `NaN + NaN = NaN` (still Not a Number).

So I guess your expression evaluates as `(undefined * 1) + (undefined * 1) = NaN + NaN = NaN`

Both `USWIPQtyValue` and `UKWIPQtyValue` must be set like:

```
var item = {
    USWIPQtyValue: 0,
    UKWIPQtyValue: 0
};
```